# Quantization error in ADCs and sampling speed

Tags: adc, oversampling

Assertion: The noise due to quantization error for an *ideal* 12-bit ADC gives a signal to noise ratio of 74dB, assuming a signal with full dynamic range at the input.

Suppose I was using an ideal ADC to sample a noiseless analogue signal (i.e. analogue circuitry did not introduce any additional noise to the original input signal). And suppose I was using a low pass filter such that signal attenuation at 1kHz was -74dB. Is it true to say that sampling at greater than 2kHz is called oversampling, and that oversampling will not improve the SNR?

Edit1: 'Low pass filter' is an *analogue* filter in the above question

Edit2: Bode plot added. fs=2kHz, fa=50Hz.[image: Filter Bode plot]

Comment: Your assertion is wrong for a dynamic signal. If you sample at 1000 Sps and your signal is 400 Hz you will have a significant quantization noise and your actual 400 Hz spectrum will be several dB lower than if the signal were (say) 40 Hz (or) 4 Hz.

Comment: @Andyaka - I don't understand your comment. Surely, assuming a brick wall reconstruction filter the 400Hz component will be of full amplitude with the quantization noise spread over 0-500Hz at a -74dBfs level.

Comment: @Andyaka. Can I add the following caveat then, please: My bandwidth of interest only contains signals at 0dB. For example, bandwidth of interest is 0-50Hz and these are all attenuated 0dB. 400Hz may be attenuated (say -20dB for the sake of argument) but I'm not interested in signals more than 50Hz.

Comment: @KevinWhite Hi. Please may I ask where '0-500Hz' comes from?

Comment: @KevinWhite as you approach nyquist, the hold region becomes bigger and the spectral content of the baseband signal falls rapidly until exactly at nyquist where it is indeterminate. This is why anti-sinc filters are employed on the outputs of DACs. Read this:https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3853

Comment: @DB17 - That's the Nyquist limit for 1000Hz sampling. What Andy is saying about the anti-sync filters is true, I wasn't sure if he was referring to that in his previous comment. At 400Hz the sin(x)/x loss will be about 2.5dB with 1000Hz sampling rate.

Comment: @KevinWhite. Thanks. I tried to clarify my question by adding that I'm only talking about components from 0 to 50Hz. My filter passes these at 0dB and then rolls off. I was speculating that a sampling speed of 2kHz would be sufficient for the 0 to 50Hz band, assuming that attenuation was -74dB at 1kHz. Any faster sampling speed would not lower the noise floor?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their contributions, especially @Andyaka. Just going back to my original question, I'm still not clear that it's been answered. (Has it?) To restate: For a 12-bit ADC, if my bandwidth of interest is 0 to fa, is there any point increasing fs if the attenuation at fs/2 is -74dB? Sorry to labour the issue! I just can't find an answer to this direct question having searched around.

Comment: @DB17 Yes to answer your question absolutely it will improve your SNR to the extent you are limited by quantization noise and the actual spurious free dynamic range of the ADC is sufficient. Basically you will achieve the performance of a higher range ADC by oversampling. I will detail this below. And to clarify AndyAka's comment about the Sinc roll-off; I believe that is only applicable only to DAC's but not ADC's. (It is the staircase reconstruction of DAC's specifically that causes the roll-off).

Comment: Actually I already provided an answer here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40259/what-are-advantages-of-having-higher-sampling-rate-of-a-signal/40261#40261

Comment: @DanBoschen Thank you for your comment; the link that you gave was illuminating and gets to the nub of the problem. I'm still processing your answer on that other thread. My immediate take-away from that link was that oversampling can reduce the quantization noise if, _and only if_, the data is filtered digitally after sampling. Would that be a fair comment?

Comment: If you are concerned only with total noise power then yes it will reduce that power by filtering to the extent we can model that noise as a distributed noise process (spurs in practical implementations will ultimately limit the ability to keep adding bits.) However many processes are sensitive to noise density and as such do filter the signal that may not be as obvious as an actual filter implementation. So a broader more accurate statement; oversamping will reduce the noise density (power/Hz).

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't true at all.

Even if quantization noise is the only source of error in your system, oversampling allows you to spread that noise over a wider bandwidth, and [noise shaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_shaping) allows you to move most of the noise energy to a frequency band that you don't care about, improving the SNR in the band of interest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I may not have framed my question correctly. Let's assume that my bandwidth of interest is 0-50Hz. I'm not interested in frequencies above 50Hz. My filter is 0dB up to 50Hz and then starts to roll off, such that it is -74dB at 1kHz. Would sampling at >2kHz reduce the noise in the 0-50Hz band? (Assume I am not doing any digital signal manipulation.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all if your signal of interest is 50 Hz maximum then providing your sampling rate is greater than twice 50 Hz you don't need an anti alias filter. However, sampling at a higher rate does improve the ability to restore that signal back to an analogue waveform without loss of amplitude. Consider these two scenarios: -

[image]

In the top picture a waveform is sampled 20 times per cycle and in the lower waveform it is sampled at only 10 times per cycle. Clearly, there is more noise in the signal that is sampled fewer times per cycle even though the sampling rate is still significantly greater that the nyquist rate.

That noise is "out of band" and, when reconstructed with a DAC, it can be filtered away but, using a flat filter will result in an observed attenuation of higher frequency base band signals.

It probably can't be easily seen but, the RMS values of both sampled waveforms are identical but one contains more sampling noise than the other hence its baseband spectrum *must be* reduced.

Consider a sinewave sampled about \$2\frac{2}{3}\$ times per cycle: -

[image]

Because the RMS of the sampled waveform AND the RMS of the unsampled waveform are identical, AND, there is clearly more noise in the sampled waveform, the spectral content of the baseband signal that is contained in the sampled signal MUST have reduced.

This means that sampling at a higher frequency can avoid an anti-sinc filter.

Comment: Whoa! I never knew about that relationship regarding r.m.s. values. Thank you so much for putting that together to explain, I don't recall seeing that in any textbook. Taking your 10Hz and 20Hz examples, one can see that, as the sampling frequency is increased, the difference between sample amplitudes in successive readings decreases. At some high sampling frequency F, this amplitude difference will be equal to the ADC resolution. Assuming that no digital averaging is performed, is there any point sampling faster than F?

Comment: You need to sample at more than twice the highest frequency or you will get aliasing. Aliasing is the sampling noise moving into the baseband spectral area.

Comment: Why do you say noise is greater in low sampling frequencies? That’s not true. Your analysis of the visual appearance of higher quantization error in time domain is not accurate. Quantization noise is due to the fact that the original signal is sampled with an error of +- 1/2 LSB, this has nothing to do with sampling frequency.

Comment: @PDuarte I think you need to study more carefully what I’ve said and drawn. The 0.5 LSb thing you mention is preposterous. I’ve assumed perfect infinite quantisation and if your attitude is to downvote first and ask questions later then that won’t make you friends.

Comment: @Andyaka I’m sorry if I offended you. That was not my intention. Back to the problem, if you didn’t consider the quantization noise in your explanation then it’s even worse because nyquist theorem says you can perfectly reconstruct the signal in both cases of your first two charts. Why did you state “Clearly there is more noise in the signal that is sampled fewer times per cycle”? That’s what I’m saying is not accurate

Comment: @PDuarte sure there is more noise when the waveform is sampled fewer times per cycle but nowhere have I said that you can't reconstruct the signal (that would be wrong). That noise is above the baseband and can be removed by filtering. However, if you sample fewer times per cycle, that noise spreads down towards the baseband and this makes it harder to filter out because you need a much steeper filter. Plus you lose amplitude of the baseband signal when it is sampled fewer times per cycle. Both the downward spreading noise and the loss of amplitude making a recovery filter harder to design.

Comment: @Andyaka I believe I understood what you meant. But the "noise" word is what made things confusing to me. What you actually mean by "noise" in the time domain comparison is resolution, and it doesn't degrade the signal as a real noise would, like quantization noise. The noise you refer to after the baseband, which I also wouldn't call it noise because again, it does't degrade the signal, is the aliasing effect and it only relates to the resolution shifting it in the frequency domain. There's no higher aliasing effect in magnitude if you change the resolution.

Comment: @Andyaka I suggest you use a more appropriate word to describe the effects in your explanation. Again, I'm trying to engage in a productive discussion. If I see that the answer is accurate there's no reason to down vote it.

Comment: @PDuarte well, what would you call what I call noise? Maybe "sampling artefacts"? Everyone else seems to refer to it as noise.

Comment: @Andyaka Like i said, sampling resolution. But I’m not sure if your text would be coherent once you used noise to compare RMS magnitudes. Sorry, i believe you need to rewrite it with the correct concepts.

Comment: So what would you call what I refer to as noise?